# What kind of data references live in a SwiftUI viewmodel?

Tags: swiftui, mvvm

This isn't just a philosophical question; it's a real design issue. I'm wrestling with how to expose the application's central data model to UIs.

Whatever you want to call them, the objects handling the data structures presented by the views are supposed to be brokering changes to the data model that result from user actions in the views. And the views are always supposed to show "live" data even if said data are updated in the background.

Take this simple example:
[image]

So how is this supposed to be accomplished in SwiftUI? There could be a process churning away downloading messages in the background, updating the data model.

And don't get hung up on the specific datatypes here. I might be talking about changes to the User object that take place while the user is viewing a representation of it.

Compounding the difficulty occasionally is that SwiftUI can only monitor changes to value types; changes published from class (non-struct) child objects aren't propagated outside the parent.

In SwiftUI tutorials, Apple evangelizes a "sole source of truth" idea, but I can't see how that is achievable given the requirement of a broker between the UI and the central model. It is obviously inadvisable to bind the UI directly to the central data model, which is the sole source of truth. So... what am I missing here?

To follow up on some comments: I'm not using CoreData or the like because this needs to be ported cross-platform and I want to avoid proprietary binding like that. Also I'm targeting iOS 15+.

It seems to me that I need to go back to using notifications or a delegate pattern to alert all viewmodels that the central model has changed. Then the viewmodels will what? Toggle a flag within themselves to trigger a UI refresh? And it'll refresh from what? Wrapper functions in the viewmodel that pull data from the central model?

Comment: View and ViewModel are the only thing that should be concerned with UI. A Manager or Service can use Combine to communicate with the View/ViewModel. You can create custom property wrappers that can do it all. You can also use notifications or tools like CoreData/SwiftData to be intermediaries. The new Observable macro can be very useful. It just a matter of choosing a design approach. There isn’t one way of doing this it all depends on your app, use case, number of users, amount of data.

Comment: Exactly, hence the question, thanks. I'm not using CoreData or the like because this needs to be ported cross-platform and I want to avoid proprietary binding like that. I haven't found a way to bind the UI to a wrapper in the viewmodel that then manipulates the data model. I haven't used Combine; I'm targeting iOS 15+, and Apple has only lately started filling some glaring holes... for iOS 17+.

Comment: SwiftUI property wrappers won’t work inside of a class, there is no way to do that. You need Combine or some other way like Dependency Injection. But note that SwiftUI isn’t at its most performant with ObservableObjects as ViewModels. There are specific cases that warrant this but 99% of the time with any growing app you will reach the point where you will feel how bad they are.

Comment: Indeed. So what do you suggest injecting as a dependency? I do in fact have a "user state" enum in my injected "user manager" object, which the UI binds to and the manager updates as user info is downloaded. But the manager is not notified if a background process changes the central data model. As far as I can see, I have to go back to a notification or delegate arrangement for that.

Comment: I’m big on dependency injection for services and managers, this works with any architecture. Having a “factory” of sorts that provides the service/manager. I don’t like TCA but they use this approach somewhat (IMO it kinda goes overboard). There is also the MongoDB/Realm approach that mimicks Apple’s CoreData structure. I also use CoreData as a “cache” for data heavy apps, the benefits of faulting cannot be duplicated. It just depends on the app, there is no right answer.

Comment: Yep, in fact I'm injecting a "management" array with the essential controllers into the views when I instantiate them, from which they can choose the managers they need. Those are basically singletons at the moment, but I'm injecting them anyway for future flexibility. But back to the original issue: I've pretty much resigned to going with notifications, which kinda sucks but ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: That works… don’t forget you can create your own property wrappers to hide all of that. But you can use Combine. CurrentValueSubject is a great friend for a manager.

Answer (score 1):

In SwiftUI the `View` structs are the view model already you don't need separate objects for view data. The `View` structs create dependencies on the model data and `body` is called whenever the model data changes creating a new hierarchy of View structs (it's like a model's "onChange"). Since `View` structs are values it is negligible performance-wise to regenerate this hierarchy (as long as you don't make a mistake like initing objects). SwiftUI then diffs the struct hierarchy and uses the result to init the actual view layer automatically for you, ie it inits/deinits/updates UIKit `UIView` objects  choosing the best ones for the platform. If you try to reimplement some of this with view model objects instead that's when you'll run into performance problems and consistency bugs.

You can put static view data in lets and dynamic data in @State and pass write access with `@Binding`. Body is called on changes in all cases. Use computed vars to transform data from rich model types into simple value types as you pass it into child `View` inits. Do not pass objects or structs into child Views that don't use all of their properties because that inefficient because body might be needlessly called if a property changes that is not read in body.

You are right to question if single source of truth was a good idea, many who are having problems with non-state-driven UI events like navigation or handling deep links are beginning to question that too.

Comment: Have you seen the spatial computing videos from WWDC? They have EnvironmentObject ViewModels

Comment: I haven’t but I’m not surprised, some of the SwiftUi RealityKit APIs and samples are shocking. Eg Diorama is maybe one of the worst samples they’ve ever done, it’s like they’ve never used Swift before, take a look. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/visionos/diorama

Comment: Haven't looked at it yet, just started listening to videos today. Just surprised to see EnvironmentObject you came to mind.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful reply. The issue is that the model data aren't just changing all the time behind the back of the UI; the user is actively performing tasks and making changes that need to be applied to the model. But they need validation and the ability to cancel, so you can't just bind the UI to the model. Also, you can't bind to computed vars, so you can't use that to intervene in data modifications. I take it you guys oppose EnvironmentObject? EnvironmentObject strikes me as very hokey.